# QxcbConnection Error!

Tags: linux, command-line, compiling

I am trying to run a program namely "rosnode" by entering command "rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node". The command is suppose to open up a window of program, but what it does is give the following error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try below commands and then try again

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Comment: I tried both commands, but gives the same error except the corresponding 0 or 0.0 at the end of display.

Comment: I googled it a bit and people were suggesting some ssh, but I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: it does not work

Comment: Actually, I was doing this in Windows 10 Ubuntu shell, which at that time did not support a GUI. That most probably was the issue.